# Weird behavior with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, web-hosting, ovh

I'm new in rewrite rule and I encounter a little issue with my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^toto\.html$ /toto.php [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(my|your)/template\.html [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(my|your)/example\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^\.]*)\.html$ /$1.php?type=$2&name=$3 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^\.]*)\.html$ /index.php?type=$1&name=$2 [L]
RedirectMatch 404 \.(htaccess|htpasswd|ini|log|sh|inc|bak|bkp|sql|json)$
```

I tested it on https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ which always give me the right rewrite.

When I test it on my webhosting :

I go to http://mydomain.ovh/my/object.html

The rewrite is **right** : http://mydomain.ovh/index.php?type=my&name=object

But when I go to

- http://mydomain.ovh/write/my/object.html
- http://mydomain.ovh/extract/my/object.html
- http://mydomain.ovh/fill/your/object.html
- http://mydomain.ovh/write/your/data.html
- http://mydomain.ovh/extract/your/data.html

The rewrite is **wrong** : The requested URL /redirect:.php was not found on this server.

I don't understand this behavior...

So I tested new rewrite rules making a common script for write/fill action :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^toto\.html$ /toto.php [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/extract/(my|your)/[^\.]+\.html$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^\.]*)\.html$ /extract.php?type=$2&name=$3 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/extract.* [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(my|your)/template\.html [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(my|your)/example\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^\.]*)\.html$ /set.php?type=$2&name=$3 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^\.]*)\.html$ /index.php?type=$1&name=$2 [L]
RedirectMatch 404 \.(htaccess|htpasswd|ini|log|sh|inc|bak|bkp|sql|json)$
```

I tested it on https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ which always give me the right rewrite.

And when I test it on my webhosting :

I go to http://mydomain.ovh/my/object.html

The rewrite is **right** : http://mydomain.ovh/index.php?type=my&name=object

I go to http://mydomain.ovh/fill/my/object.html or http://mydomain.ovh/write/your/data.html

The rewrite is **right** : http://mydomain.ovh/set.php?type=my&name=object or http://mydomain.ovh/set.php?type=your&name=data

But when I go to http://mydomain.ovh/extract/my/object.html or http://mydomain.ovh/extract/your/data.html

The rewrite is always **wrong** : the request reach the script but without query string... (and it appear to be a redirect?)

```
["PATH_TRANSLATED"]=>
string(19) "redirect:/index.php"
["PATH_INFO"]=>
string(30) "/my/object.html"
["SCRIPT_NAME"]=>
string(11) "/extract.php"
["REQUEST_URI"]=>
string(37) "/extract/my/object.html"
["QUERY_STRING"]=>
string(0) ""
["PHP_SELF"]=>
string(41) "/extract.php/my/object.html"
```

Can someone help with these rewrite rules ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to turn off option `MultiViews` at top of your .htaccess which it seems is turned on for your website in Apache config.

Add this at top of your .htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

Option `MultiViews` (see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/content-negotiation.html) is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs **before** `mod_rewrite` and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So if `/file` is the URL then Apache will serve `/file.html`.

Once you make this change, test in a new browser to avoid old browser cache.